# Angular 5 : template parse error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I'm trying to create a component(a div with a button to go back to previous extent) which can be used throughout the application , like this

**ZoomHistory.ts** ,

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Renderer2, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

//import { olControl} from 'ol/control/control';


@Component({
  selector: 'prevview',
  template: '<div></div>'
  //styles: [require('./map.scss')],
})

export class ZoomHistoryComponent  {

  @ViewChild('maptoolelement')
  private element: ElementRef;

  static parameters = [ElementRef, Renderer2, ViewChild];
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {

    //super();      
    const backButton = this.renderer.createElement('button');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(backButton, 'class', 'ol-navhist-back');
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = '../images/zoom-last.png';
    img.alt = "Previous view";
    backButton.appendChild(img);

    renderer.listen(backButton, 'click', (event) => {

      // Do something with 'event'
    })

    this.renderer.appendChild(this.element, backButton);

  }
}
```

and i'm exporting this at **map.module.ts**

```
import { ZoomHistoryComponent } from '../maptools/zoomhistory/zoomhistory';

@NgModule({
  providers: [    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(mapRoutes),

  ],
  declarations: [
    MapComponent,
    ZoomHistoryComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    MapComponent,
    ZoomHistoryComponent
  ],
})
export class MapModule { }
```

in **app.module.ts** , I'm importing this as follows ,

```
import { MapModule } from './map/map.module';

@NgModule({
  providers,
  imports: [

    MapModule]
}),
```

but when I put this component at map.html

```
 <prevview></prevview>
```

its throwing error like ,

*compiler.js:486 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'prevview' is not a known element:
1. If 'prevview' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
      
      [ERROR ->]*

Comment: You've got MapTwoModule and MapModule. Is it normal? And what is map.html? Is is the template for MapComponent, which is declared in the same module as ZoomHIstoryComponent?

Comment: edited , was a typo , map,html has some div , like    <div class="mapcontainer"> </div>

Comment: Ok, but what is map.html? Is it the template for the MapComponent referred in your post? Or for another component in another module

Comment: yes , its a template for mapcomponent